# How to implement google maps with laravel and vue js to observe the distance in real time that the user walks?

Tags: laravel, google-maps, vue.js

I am building a web application with Laravel and Vue JS. The idea of ​​this application is that the user who uses the application must perform challenges and training exercises. I need to create a section where the user can see the distance he walks in real time.

I am using [vue2-google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps) and I currently have the following code.

```php
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h2>Search and add a pin</h2>
      <label>
        <gmap-autocomplete
          @place_changed="setPlace">
        </gmap-autocomplete>
        <button @click="addMarker">Add</button>
      </label>
      <br/>

    </div>
    <br>
    <gmap-map
      :center="center"
      :zoom="12"
      style="width:100%;  height: 400px;"
    >
      <gmap-marker
        :key="index"
        v-for="(m, index) in markers"
        :position="m.position"
        @click="center=m.position"
      ></gmap-marker>
    </gmap-map>
  </div>
</template>



<script>
export default {
  name: "GoogleMap",
  data() {
    return {
      // default to Montreal to keep it simple
      // change this to whatever makes sense
      center: { lat: 45.508, lng: -73.587 },
      markers: [],
      places: [],
      currentPlace: null
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.geolocate();
  },

  methods: {
    // receives a place object via the autocomplete component
    setPlace(place) {
      this.currentPlace = place;
    },
    addMarker() {
      if (this.currentPlace) {
        const marker = {
          lat: this.currentPlace.geometry.location.lat(),
          lng: this.currentPlace.geometry.location.lng()
        };
        this.markers.push({ position: marker });
        this.places.push(this.currentPlace);
        this.center = marker;
        this.currentPlace = null;
      }
    },
    geolocate: function() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        this.center = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

But I'm not sure if with vue2-google-maps I can achieve what I'm trying to do. I need help and suggestions, please.

Answer (score 1):

it's definitely doable, you just need to set an interval to geolocate your position every N seconds and then push points and draw the polyline that marks your path. Then you probably have to save all the points server side to keep an history of your trainings and you can also use sockets to send updates to all clients connected if you want to show them your position in realtime

Answer (score 0):

It should be doable. Looking into this `<GmapMarker />` component is a good start. From a UI standpoint, you could customize the [marker's `icon`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Icon) (with, say, some avatar icon). And when you have the distance calculation logic in place, "animating" the marker should be just a matter of updating the [`position`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerOptions.position) property as a user progresses with the training and/or exercises.

**References**:

- [vue2-google-maps API documentation](http://xkjyeah.github.io/vue-google-maps/autoapi.html)
- [Customizing a Google Map marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers), or alternatively, [vue2-gmap-custom-marker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-gmap-custom-marker).